# How to get my Android device GPS location via Here API?

Tags: here-api

How to get my Android device GPS location via here-api?

I want to know my current latitude and longitude in order to center the Here-maps to that location. I am using the JavaScript API.

Thank you.

Comment: the documentation is Here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/map-positioning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PositioningManager class should be helpful for this. PositioningManager.getPosition() should give you the current position of the device after PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod) is called.